# merging two unsorted singly-linked lists

Tags: java, merge, linked-list

I wrote a function that merges two unsorted singly-linked lists. I simply add each node from the second list to the front of the original list. It seems to work except that when i print the original, now merged list, the newly added elements are 'null'

```
public SLL mergeUnsorted(SLL otherList)
{
    Iterator itr = otherList.iterator() ;
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        Object elem  = itr.next() ;
        System.out.println(elem) ; // to make sure the elements are retrieved correctly
        SLLNode ins = new SLLNode(elem, null) ; // make a node out of the element 
        ins.succ = this.first ; // insert the element to the front of the original list
        this.first = ins ;
    }
    return this ;
}
```

from main i call the function:

```
myList = myList.mergeUnsorted(otherList) ;
printIt(myList) ;
```

output:

```
null null null null Hi Hello Salut Ciao
```

SLLNode contructor:

```
public SLLNode(Object ObjElem, SLLNode succ)
{
    this.ObjElem = ObjElem ;
    this.succ = succ ;
}
```

**[EDIT]**

```
class SLL
{
    SLLNode first ;

    public SLL()
    {
        first = null ;
    }
...
```

Note1: The exercise states that the SLL class data representation only includes a first node `private SLLNode first ;`  hence i cannot use any reference to 'last' node

Note2: The exercise contains a method that i most probably will need to use but i can't see how.

```
private SLLNode node(int i)
{
    SLLNode curr = first ;
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
        curr = curr.succ ;
        }
    return curr ;
}
```

Note3: i could add the iterator implementation code here but given that i can print the list using the same Iterator it seems all correct so i'd rather not clutter this post too much. Hope that's ok?

**[EDIT2]**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SLL myList = new SLL() ;
    SLL otherList = new SLL() ;  
    SLLNode a = new SLLNode("xx", null) ;
    SLLNode b = new SLLNode("yy", null) ;
    SLLNode c = new SLLNode("ww", null) ;
    SLLNode d = new SLLNode("aa", null) ;
    SLLNode e = new SLLNode("rr", null) ;

    otherList.addFirst(a) ;
    printIt(otherList) ;
    otherList.addFirst(b) ;
    printIt(otherList) ;
    otherList.addFirst(c) ;
    printIt(otherList) ;
    otherList.addFirst(d) ;
    printIt(otherList) ;

    SLLNode A = new SLLNode("Hello", null) ;
    SLLNode B = new SLLNode("Hi", null) ;
    SLLNode C = new SLLNode("Salut", null) ;
    SLLNode D = new SLLNode("Ciao", null) ;
    SLLNode E = new SLLNode("Moin", null) ;

    myList.addFirst(A) ;
    printIt(myList) ;
    myList.addFirst(B) ;
    printIt(myList) ;
    myList.addFirst(C) ;
    printIt(myList) ;
    myList.addFirst(D) ;
    printIt(myList) ;

    myList = myList.mergeUnsorted(otherList) ;
    printIt(myList) ;
}
```

**[EDIT3]**@Paulo, complete output as generated by main included in Edit2

```
xx
yy xx
ww yy xx
aa ww yy xx
Hello
Hi Hello
Salut Hi Hello
Ciao Salut Hi Hello
aa
ww
yy
xx
null null null null Ciao Salut Hi Hello
```

note that line 9-12 are from the print statement inside the merge function

Comment: `this.first ` - post the data structure of SLL class.

Comment: @Baba What were the two lists you gave as parameter when you got that output?

Comment: @Baba Never mind, I gather from your post that one list was [Hi, Hello, Salut, Ciao]

Comment: Please put out your full code, it's hard to detect problem from the fragment

Comment: @Baba Show us your `Iterator` implementation.

Comment: @Baba: print `printIt(myList) ;` before merge...() call and see the initial data. is it prints `Hi Hello Salut Ciao`

Comment: @Baba: does `printIt()` print data from tail to head?

Comment: @Baba: if you iterate from tail to head, your initial data in myList are all null.

Comment: @John, see my Edit2, as i add nodes when i intitally construct the lists, i print the lists and when printed before the merging happens, they print out fine i.e. the values are printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you change implementation so succesor of your last node in the first list points to first node in the other list.

```
public SLL mergeUnsorted(SLL otherList)
{
    if (otherList != null && otherList.first != null) {
        SLLNode last = null;
        Iterator itr = iterator() ;
        for (itr.hasNext())
        {
            Object elem  = itr.next() ;
            if (elem.succ == null) {
                last = elem;
            }
        }
        if (last != null) {
            last.succ = otherList.first;
        }
    }    
    return this;
}
```

Comment: @Baba 'last' is a local variable in mergeUnsorted method. You just looks up in your linked list for last element (first element added to the list), and you link the other list to this first element.

Comment: i see. That actually sounds like a great idea. I will try it out but first i would like to get to bottom of the problem with the current approach

Comment: You _could_ use `SLLNode node(int i)` to find the last node in the list (try i=0 and increment until you don't get a node back -- not very efficient though).

Answer (score 0):

From your fragment it looks right (but I would use `this.first = new SLLNode(elem, this.first)` and ommit the next two statements). What did your `mergeUnsorted` method print?

---

Edit: I have no idea what is wrong, but obviously your `addFirst` method works, while directly adding does not work correctly. So use this:

```
public SLL mergeUnsorted(SLL otherList)
{
    Iterator itr = otherList.iterator() ;
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        Object elem  = itr.next() ;
        System.out.println(elem) ; // to make sure the elements are retrieved correctly
        SLLNode ins = new SLLNode(elem, null) ; // make a node out of the element 
        this.addFirst(ins);
    }
    return this ;
}
```

Of course, this will add the elements in reverse order, but the same is happening now, too (it just does not work).

Comment: @Baba: I supposed that, since it does nothing else than your already not-working method, only a bit more efficient. But **what does your `mergeUnsorted` method print?**

Comment: @Paulo, see 'output' in my initial post

Comment: @Baba: I see there only one line of output, please copy the whole output of your program (which main method you just posted).